# How can I add a 0. before an variable in python

Tags: python

Im making an python application to calculate percentages and I wanted to know how I can add an "0." in front of a variable to multiply it by the "percentOf" variable (would output the answer, but doesn't).

I've tried this:
    import sys

```
percent = input("Enter percent:")
ofNumber = input("Enter number:")

percent2 = percent++0.

answer = percent2 * ofNumber

print(answer)
```

but it won't work :(

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to divide by 100.

Comment: Do you *really* want an input of 5 to become 0.5?

Comment: Yes I do, but i'll try fuglede's answer

Comment: 5 percent is 0.05, not 0.5. If you think you want 0.5, it'd probably be a good idea to brush up on how percentages work before continuing with your program.

Comment: Yee... That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

There are two changes needed to make this work.

**Converting `input()` result to numbers:**

`input()` retrieves input from the user as text (a "string"), not as a number. To use the inputs as numbers, you'll want to convert them into integers using the builtin conversion function `int()`:

```
percent = int(input("Enter percent:"))
ofNumber = int(input("Enter number:"))
```

(In practice, you would also want to use `try`/`catch` to handle the case where the user typed something that wasn't a valid number, but we'll ignore that for now)

**Converting a Percentage Into a Decimal:**

This is the part you asked about. You can do this by dividing by 100, as stated in the comment above:

```
percent2 = percent / 100
```

---

**Final Code:**

With both of those changes:

```
percent = int(input("Enter percent:"))
ofNumber = int(input("Enter number:"))

percent2 = percent / 100

answer = percent2 * ofNumber

print(answer)
```

Sample output:

```
> Enter percent:20
> Enter number:100
> 20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative solotion!

It works by multiplying the percent by the percentOf and then dividing that by 100.
The code is this:

```
import sys

percent = input("Enter percent (%):")
ofNumber = input("Enter number:")

var1 = ofNumber * percent

answer = var1 / 100

print(answer)
```

Comment: If that worked, you're on Python 2. You should really get Python 3. Also, your code will report that 5 percent of 10 is 0, due to Python 2-specific division behavior.